# Why does Google API set +01 offset no matter input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-calendar-api, datetime-format

I'm using Google's API Explorer for their Calendar API on [this page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples).

I am inserting an event `{ "end": { "dateTime": "2016-10-31T06:30:00Z" }, "start": { "dateTime": "2016-10-31T06:00:00Z" } }`  and have tried the following datetime formats:

```
2016-10-31T06:00:00Z
2016-10-31T06:00:00-00:00
2016-10-31T06:00:00+00:00
```

But no matter input format, Google chooses to add an hour when setting the datetime. The response is always:

```
"start": {
 "dateTime": "2016-10-31T07:00:00+01:00"
}
```

I'm currently in Stockholm, which has +2 hours offset. I've tried both setting the separate time_zone field and omitting the separate time_zone field.

Why is this happening? And, is there any "right way" or do I simply need to take this added hour into account when setting time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the [`timeZone`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#request-body) property to specify the time zone properly.

Sample request using the `"timeZone":`[`"Europe/Stockholm"`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones):

```
{
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2016-10-31T06:30:00",
  "timeZone": "Europe/Stockholm"
 },
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2016-10-31T06:00:00",
  "timeZone": "Europe/Stockholm"
 }
}
```