# Google calendar timezone is not proper

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am sending below array to google api for saving an event into google calendar but it is displaying on wrong time.
Can anyone help me please ?

```
Array
(
[summary] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[location] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[description] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[start] => Array
    (
        [dateTime] => 2017-01-25T09:00:00+0000
        [timeZone] => America/Toronto
    )

[end] => Array
    (
        [dateTime] => 2017-01-25T09:30:00+0000
        [timeZone] => America/Toronto
    )

[attendees] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [email] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [email] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            )

    )

[reminders] => Array
    (
        [useDefault] => 
        [overrides] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [method] => email
                        [minutes] => 1440
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [method] => popup
                        [minutes] => 10
                    )

            )

    )
```

I am sending 9:00 - 9:30 time to save an event but it is displaying as 25th Jan 2017, 4:00-4:30 in my google calendar. I am using PHP google calendar api.
Thanks

Comment: The '+0000' specified the timezone. What happens if you change that to '-0500' which is Toronto's timezone. Or drop that all together and use the 'timeZone' statement (which would be better, as then it'll cope with Summertime Savings)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Robbie, Yes it works perfectly for static dates.
I have something like this
`
$Start = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($date));
'start' => array(
  'dateTime' => $Start->format(DateTime::ISO8601),
                'timeZone' => 'America/Toronto',
           ),
`
Can you please help how to make -'05:00' with this format ?
Thanks

Comment: If i deduct 5 hours from the date I am sending, it would work but I am thinking that is not the correct way to do it. Deducting 5 hours from date may work for my location only. Is there any way which makes it dynamic and set time as per my location ?

Comment: The -0500 IS the timezone. You don't need to deduct it from the time. `2017-01-25T09:30:00-0500` means 9:30am in Toronto, `2017-01-25T09:30:00=1000` is 9:30am in Sydney.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dateTime field specifies the point in time when the event takes place and the timezone is just the decoration for displaying this to the user in their timezone (unless the offset has been omitted, then the offset of the timezone is taken into consideration). The offset in dateTime field matters for the time evaluation (in your case you specified +0000 which means "no offset from UTC").

You have three options:

- specify the time in UTC 2017-01-25T14:00:00+0000 (or better 2017-01-25T14:00:00Z)
- specify the time with the Toronto offset 
  2017-01-25T09:00:00-0500
- omit the offset altogether 2017-01-25T09:00:00

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can only put `2017-01-25T09:00:00` without `+0000`. You'll use the [`timeZone`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#request-body) property to specify the time zone properly.

You may check my answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40236334/5832311).

```
{
 "end": {
    "dateTime": "2017-01-25T09:30:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Toronto"
 },
 "start": {
    "dateTime": "2017-01-25T09:00:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Toronto"
 }
}
```

I have tested it using the API explorer and it works properly.